# UK visa: applying between jobs

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-employment

I'd like to apply and travel to UK for vacation between my jobs (i.e. quitting current job and want to visit UK before starting the next one).

What document should I produce that says: "employment letter detailing the role/salary/length of employment". Can I just give the new employer's offer letter as a proof (has the start date although a couple months in the future)?

Answer (score 2):

You can provide them with your last 6 month pay slips from your former company and also make sure you provide your payroll bank statement that reflects your income from the previous employment. Besides, you better write a cover letter that explains your situation.

Comment: I agree with the cover letter. Why 6 mo payslip? I don't mind but those will be a lot (12 pages for bimonthly). Isn't it better to just give bank statement showing that I have enough funds to cover my stay?

Comment: The pay slips can be the proof of your last employment and beside that, bank statement itself is not enough, it still need to be supported by docs that can tell the source of the income (which is the pay slip). Anw, if 6mos will be too much, I think 3mos will work.